# Finding a dynamically added control in a third nested repeater

Tags: .net, findcontrol, datarepeater

I have three repeaters. Lets call them R1, R2 and R3.

In `R3`, I create a bunch of controls in `Page_Init`. For example, one of those controls has the name `WMC_image`.

Im using this code to get R2:

```
Page.FindControl("R1").Controls[1].FindControl("R2")
```

This works fine. But when I add the code to get R3:

```
Page.FindControl("R1").Controls[1].FindControl("R2").Controls[1].FindControl("R3")
```

I get the error:

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: index".

How come I get this error? And how do I fetch the HtmlGenericControl inside of R3?

EDIT: Sorry but I forgot to add that only R1 get filled DataBind() in the Page_Init. The other two Repeaters gets filled in the OnItemDataBound event.

When I loop out all controls in R1, I get a bunch of hits. But I get nothing from R2 even tho' I can see them on my site.

Comment: Thats why it's not recommended to use multiple dots on the same line. Try this: 

Control r1 = Page.FindControl("R1");
ControlCollection rcCol = r1.Controls[1];
Control r2 = rcCo.FindControl("R2");
ControlCollection rc2Col = r2.Controls[1];
Control r3 = rc2Col.FindControl("R3");</code>

Comment: Thanks! But: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection'"

Comment: ControlCollection doesnt seem to work with FindControl? Atleast I can't use it like that..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in one line you need to do this in multiple lines:

You'll probably want to add some error checking as well

```
Control R1;
Control R2;
Control R3;    

if (Page.HasControls()) {
  R1 = Page.FindControl("R1").Controls[1]
  if ( R1.HasControls()) {
    R2 = R1.FindControl("R2").Controls[1]
    if (R2.HasControls()) {
      R3 = R2.FindControl("R3")
    }
  }
}
```